# automatically create table on sequelize.js + next.js

Tags: mysql, next.js, sequelize.js

I have fullstack nextjs project and for connecting to mysql database I am using sequelize.js.
Consider I have a comments table and at first this table does not exist but I want this table to be created automatically whenever I insert something in it.

*I know I should use sequelize.sync() method to achieve it but the problem is if I manually delete table from 'phpmyadmin' it will not be created again unless I try to refresh app multiple times.

/src/db/connection.ts:

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
const makeConnection = () => {
    const { DB_NAME, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD } = process.env;
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, {
      host: DB_HOST,
      port: +DB_PORT,
      dialect: "mysql",
      logging: false,
    });
    const connection: Sequelize = sequelize;
    connection.sync();
    return connection;
};
export default makeConnection();
```

/src/db/models/comments.ts:

```
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import connection from "../connection";

const createCommentsModel= () => {
  class Comments extends Model {
    declare id: number;
    declare body: string;
  }
  Comments.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      body: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull: false },
    },
    {
      sequelize: connection,
      modelName: "comments",
      timestamps: false,
    }
  );
  return Comments ;
};

export default createCommentsModel();
```

/src/services/db/comment.ts:

```
import Comments from "@/src/db/models/comments";
export async function addComment({body}: {body:string}) {
  const newComment = await Comments.create({body}); 
  // *** If I manually delete 'comments' table from phpmyadmin this line will throw error that table does not exist 
  // ** but I want table to create automatically whenever I reach this line
  return newComment;
}
```